# Just to ask about function in Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am a beginner at ReactJs. I encounter a problem while building an app.
my relevant code is

```
this.state={
  displaySocialInputs: false,
}
```

I'm toggling the value using a button.
The button is performing well but couldn't understand the logic used in button.

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      displaySocialInputs: !prevState.displaySocialInputs
    }));
  }}
  className="btn btn-light"
>
  Add Social Networks Links`enter code here`
</button>
```

I want to ask how button know the value passed a`enter code here`s "prevState" to change the state value. we are not passing any value.
Hope you would understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

This fragment in your code:

```
prevState => ({
  displaySocialInputs: !prevState.displaySocialInputs
})
```

... is a callback. Essentially you are telling the framework "If you give me the current state and call it `prevState`, here is how I want to have it transformed".

You can think of it as follows:

1. Initially you create your component and set `displaySocialInputs: false` as your initial state. The component remembers that.
2. When the button is clicked, setState is called.
3. setState retrieves the current state and invokes the callback you have given it, passing the state as the `prevState` parameter for you.

Thanks to this pattern you don't have to give it a state yourself: the framework does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The 'toggling' is done here:

```
displaySocialInputs: !prevState.displaySocialInputs
```

The **! Operator** change the values from true to false and vice versa, i.e:

!TRUE = FALSE
!FALSE = TRUE

Answer (score 1):

In your case, prevstate is not necessary.

```
<button
 type="button"
 onClick={() => {
 this.setState({ displaySocialInputs: !this.state.displaySocialInputs });
 }}
className="btn btn-light"
>
```

But I do recommend you to avoid making functions inside your jsx. 
Make a function outside your render method, and call it in your jsx

```
handleChange = () => {
  this.setState({ displaySocialInputs: !this.state.displaySocialInputs })
}
```

And in your render

```
<button
 type="button"
 onClick={this.handleChange}
 className="btn btn-light"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working because setState is a promise so you are using the response of the promise to toggle de value. I imagine that `prevState` contain previous component state. I prefer do this to old fashion:

```
this.setState({
   displaySocialInputs:!this.state.displaySocialInputs
})
```